# copy to clipboard from Firestore with Navigator.Clipboard API in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new here, and new to coding (started learning when the whole pandemic shenanigans started) right now working on a ReactJS project. one of the element I want my app to do is: on click of button copy text from Cloud Firestore.

How I have my code set up it gets today's timestamp as to when the button was pressed and pushes it to an array pressedOnDates (has dates of all the times the button was pressed) and also updates the date in lastPressedOn (last time it was pressed on) Then using Navigator.Clipboard I copy sampleMessage out of that item's document (why I used it, idk? maybe had something to do with my laziness, and maybe because I saw this feature on home brew's website and they used it, and it worked on there website) Lastly, I have a function call to a function that updates or "repulls" data from Cloud Firestore, and because I get new data fed to my components they redraw in ascending order, component that was just pressed on moves to the bottom and the component that was pressed some time ago moves to the top.

Problem I'm having: this line of code "await navigator.clipboard.writeText(item.sampleMessage);" doesn't work on iPhones or iPads, and because there is no break and it is an await the app is stuck on this broken line of code, and  1. the app never copies the sample message, and 2. (even though it pushes new timestamps to Cloud Firestore) data never gets "repulled" and components never redraw. this code works perfectly fine on MacBook and Android phone (at least as I intended: pushes Timestamp, copies message, and redraws)

Here's my code:

```js
const handleUpdateDate = async (itemID, item) => {
    try {
      const todayTimestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
      await db
        .collection('sample')
        .doc(itemID)
        .update({
          pressedOnDates: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(todayTimestamp),
          lastPressedOn: todayTimestamp,
        });
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(item.sampleMessage);
      await updateItems();
    } catch ({ message }) {
      console.error(`Error @ handleUpdateDate, Error:${message}`);
    }
  };
```

If you can please help me out and point out what's wrong with my code, or suggest a different way to copy to clipboard, I would be more than grateful. Thank you to all of you in advance. May StackOverflow always have an answer to you're question. May the Dark Themes repel all your bugs . Wish you all the very best.

Comment: See if you simply need to [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-polyfill) to support an older browser. `navigator.clipboard` is a fairly recent standardization.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Interesting. I tested out polyfill, added it with yarn, then imported it import * as clipboard from 'clipboard-polyfill/text'; and changed from navigator.clipboard to just clipboard so its just await clipboard.writeText(item.sampleMessage);. and for some unknown reason to me it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@jacobvr](https://github.com/jacobvr) (good friend) helped me out on Github.
He told me to setup the fn like so:

1. copy to clipboard (navigator.clipboard)
2. push to pressedOnDates[] and update lastPressedOn
3. updateItems

His explanation: "this way you are not waiting for db call to finish to copy to clipboard"

What he proposed:

```js
const handleUpdateDate = async (itemID, item) => {
    try {
      const todayTimestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(item.sampleMessage);
      await db
        .collection('sample')
        .doc(itemID)
        .update({
          pressedOnDates: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(todayTimestamp),
          lastPressedOn: todayTimestamp,
        });
      await updateItems();
    } catch ({ message }) {
      console.error(`Error @ handleUpdateDate, Error:${message}`);
    }
  };
```

This is how I set it up ( both ways work on all devices, but copy to clipboard
has to be first action in the fn ):

```js
const copySampleMessage = async (item) => {
    try {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(item.sampleMessage);
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert(`Error @ copySampleMessage, Error:${message}`);
    }
  };

  const handleUpdatePressedOnDate = async (itemID, item) => {
    try {
      const todayTimestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
      await copySampleMessage(item);
      await db
        .collection('items')
        .doc(itemID)
        .update({
          pressedOnDates: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(todayTimestamp),
          lastPressedOn: todayTimestamp,
        });
      await updateItems();
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert(`Error @ handleUpdatePressedOnDate, Error:${message}`);
    }
  };
```

Thank you to all who responded and helped out with my question, wish y'all the best.